# SUM with group by return error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Having this two table

DEPARTMENT

```
//DEPARTMENT
D#          DNAME
-------------------
1         RESEARCH
2            IT
3          SCIENCE
```

PROJECT

```
//PROJECT
P#       D#        BUDGET
-------------------------
1001     1         22500
1002     1         22500
1003     3         50000
```

When i execute this command

```
SELECT d.D#,DNAME,sum(budget) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d,PROJECT p 
WHERE d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#;
```

I thought result will be

```
D#     DNAME     TOTAL BUDGETS
------------------------------
1     RESEARCH       45000
2        IT             0
3       SCIENCE      50000
```

but why i get this error

```
//Oracle: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All column names in SELECT list must appear in GROUP BY clause unless name is used only in an aggregate function.**

Change query to:

```
SELECT d.D#,DNAME,sum(budget) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d,PROJECT p 
WHERE d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#, DNAME;
```

---

Update for the comment:

```
SELECT d.D#, d.DNAME, NVL(SUM(p.budget), 0) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT p ON d.D#=p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#, d.DNAME;
```

Comment: okay. now fine. but if department dont have any budget should deisplay 0 .
but why my query is just to display those have budget d?

Comment: @user3553846 I have updated the asnwer. Then you must use Left Outer Join.

Comment: your result still didn't display any 0 if the department don't have the project

Comment: @user3553846: you'll need to replace `SUM(p.budget)` with `NVL(SUM(p.budget), 0)`.  In Oracle, a `SUM` of no data is `NULL`, not zero.

Comment: @user3553846 I have updated the asnwer. You must add NVL to check if the value is null, then replace it with 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.D#,max(DNAME),sum(budget) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d,PROJECT p 
WHERE d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#;
```

You should either include the field in `GROUP BY` section or use aggregate function (`MAX` or `MIN` is ok for the case)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to declare the `d.DNAME` column in the **GROUP BY** statement:

```
SELECT d.D#,d.DNAME,sum(BUDGET) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d,PROJECT p 
WHERE d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#, d.DNAME;
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/965d46/1)

If you want to display all departments, you need to use the **LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT d.D#,d.DNAME,sum(BUDGET) as "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
    FROM DEPARTMENT d
LEFT JOIN PROJECT p
ON d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#, d.DNAME;
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/965d46/2)

To display 0 if no projects are present you need to use the **CASE** statement

```
SELECT d.D#,d.DNAME,
CASE WHEN sum(BUDGET) IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE sum(BUDGET) END AS "TOTAL BUDGETS" 
FROM DEPARTMENT d
LEFT JOIN PROJECT p
ON d.D# = p.D#
GROUP BY d.D#, d.DNAME;
```

Output:

```
   D#   DNAME   TOTAL BUDGETS
    2   IT  0
    1   RESEARCH    45000
    3   SEARCH  50000
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/965d46/4)